# Can someone clarify for me about the global variable in this shell script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Here's the code.

```
#!/bin/bash
var_change() {
 local var1='local 1'
 echo Inside function: var1 is $var1 : var2 is $var2
 var1='changed again'
 var2='2 changed again'

}

var1='global 1'
var2='global 2'
echo Before function call: var1 is $var1 : var2 is $var2
var_change
echo After function call: var1 is $var1 : var2 is $var2
```

And here's the output when executing the above script.

```
Before function call: var1 is global 1 : var2 is global 2
Inside function: var1 is local 1 : var2 is global 2
After function call: var1 is global 1 : var2 is 2 changed again
```

Just take a look at the final line which is After function call. I don't understand why var2 here is "2 changed again". I just thought that outside of the function var_change, the var2 variable must be global2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function, `var2` is not declared `local`, and therefore it is "global", which means that the value it has at the end of the function will be the value it has after the call of the function.

Said differently, the variable `var1` within the function is "local" and therefore it is *not the same variable* as the global one of the same name, whereas this is not the case for `var2`.

Comment: Ah i got it! Seems like i was wrong about the executing order in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
local var2='local 2'
```

to the function should change that.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  The script is clearly intended as a demonstration script, to learn how scoped variables work in bash.  Changing the scope of the variables so they're all the same won't help the Original Poster learn what he is trying to learn.